# Django urls and filtering , the right way to achieve this

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I have a web app to search for cars. On the landing page, I can either enter a keyword and search or go to a link that displays all the data with filters.
So my URLs,

```
url(r'^cars/$', search, name='search'), ==> does an elastic search
url(r'^select/', select, name='select'),==> has links to filter results and pass query set
```

When I enter a keyword (say Audi) and search, the URL becomes localhost:8000/cars/?search=Audi
and if I click on the link it simply says localhost:8000/select/

Both of these views(search and select) render the same template.
Now, I want to filter the results or add more criteria. What should be the right approach to do this?
One of the websites where I got inspired for doing this project simply redirects to 
/cars?search=Audi and on clicking any link to filter redirects to /cars/Audi/BMW/Sedan 
 Is this possible in Django?

Here is the select view code. I am still learning Django and python, so, please bear with me.

```
def select(request):
    q1 = request.GET.get('brand')
    q2 = request.GET.get('model')
    q3 = request.GET.get('bodyStyle')
    q4 = request.GET.get('budget[]')
    q5 = request.GET.get('transmission')
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    print(q1)
    s1 = request.POST.get('sortBy')



    budarray = request.GET.getlist('budget')
    brandarray = request.GET.getlist('brand')
    modelarray = request.GET.getlist('model')
    bodyarray = request.GET.getlist('bodyStyle')
    transmissionarray = request.GET.getlist('transmission')


    cars = product_details.objects.all()
    posturl=""


    if len(brandarray)>0:
                    brandarray=list(dict.fromkeys(brandarray))
                    cars = cars.filter(brand_name__in=brandarray)


    if len(modelarray)>0:
                    cars = cars.filter(model_name__in=modelarray)

    if len(bodyarray)>0:
                    cars = cars.filter(bodystyle__in=bodyarray)

    if len(transmissionarray)>0:
                    cars = cars.filter(transmission__in=transmissionarray)



    minp=0
    maxp=0
    denom=""

    arraybud =[]
    if len(budarray)>0:
                for items in budarray:
                    budgetval = GetBudget(items)


                    minp=int(budgetval[0])
                    maxp=int(budgetval[1])
                    denom=budgetval[2]
                    arraybud.append(minp)
                    arraybud.append(maxp)



    minprice=0
    maxprice=0

    if len(budarray)>0:
        minprice=min(arraybud)
        maxprice=max(arraybud)
       if minp>100:
            cars=cars.filter(min_price__gt=minprice).filter(denomination='Crore')
            denom="Crores"
        else:
            denom="Lakhs"
            cars=cars.filter(min_price__gt=minprice,min_price__lt=maxprice).filter(denomination=denom)

    sort = GetOrderBy(s1)


    if sort =="nothing":
        cars = cars.order_by('model_name','min_price')
    else:
        cars = cars.order_by('model_name',sort)

    cars = cars.distinct('model_name')

    totalResult = cars.count()
    if totalResult >= 50:
        paginator = Paginator(cars, 25)
    else:
        paginator = Paginator(cars, 10)

    try:
        cars = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        cars = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        cars = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    print(request.get_full_path)

    _brands = products.objects.all()

    _models= product_models.objects.all()

    _bodystyles = product_bodystyle.objects.all()
    posturl = "Y"

    hyundaicars = product_details.objects.filter(brand_name='Hyundai').distinct('model_name')
    tatamotors = product_details.objects.filter(brand_name='Tata').distinct('model_name')
    maruticars = product_details.objects.filter(brand_name='Maruti Suzuki').distinct('model_name')
    mahindracars = product_details.objects.filter(brand_name='Mahindra').distinct('model_name')
    hondacars = product_details.objects.filter(brand_name='Honda').distinct('model_name')

    for (i, item) in enumerate(budarray):
        if item == "1":
            budarray[i] = "1 - 5 Lakhs"
        if item == "2":
            budarray[i] = "5 - 10 Lakhs"
        if item == "3":
            budarray[i] = "10 - 15 Lakhs"
        if item == "4":
            budarray[i] = "15 - 20 Lakhs"
        if item == "5":
            budarray[i] = "20 - 25 Lakhs"
        if item == "6":
            budarray[i] = "25 - 50 Lakhs"
        if item == "7":
            budarray[i] = "50 - 99 Lakhs"
        if item == "8":
            budarray[i] = "Above 1 Crore"


    return render(request, 'search/search_results.html', carsdetails)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this:

file views.py:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.filters import DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer

class RetrieveCarView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = product_details.objects.all()

    model = product_details
    filter_class = ProductDetailsFilter
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    ordering_fields = ('brand', )
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination
    serializer_class = ProductDetailsSerializer
    renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer,)
    template_name = 'search/search_results.html'
```

file serializers.py

```
class ProductDetailsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceAttachment
        fields = ('brand', 'model', 'bodyStyle', 'transmission')
        # in fields it`s needed to list fields from product_details which will be shown in html template
```

file filters.py

```
import rest_framework_filters as filters


class  ProductDetailsFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    # here are defined fields by which there is a need to filter
    brand = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='brand')
    bodyStyle = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='bodyStyle')
    transmission = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='transmission')
    budget = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='budget')
    model = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='model')

class Meta:
    model = product_details
    fields = {
        'brand': ['exact', 'in'],
        'bodyStyle: ['exact', 'in'],
        'transmission': ['exact', 'in'],
        'budget': ['exact', 'in'],
        'model': ['exact', 'in']
    }
```

file paginators.py

```
class from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from rest_framework.response import Response


class LargeResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    return Response(data)
```

In the end you will be able to filter this way:

select/?model=Audi&transmission__in=1,2&page=1&page_size=1